# For a tree with $n$ nodes and root $r$, prove the sum of length of paths from each vertex to $r \leq \binom{n}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

Basically the title, hopefully it makes sense. If I take the sum of all the lengths of the paths from each vertex to the root, I need to prove it is $\leq \binom{n}{2}$.

I'm having a hard time coming up with a way to relate the two things. Can anyone maybe offer a suggestion on where to start?

I've tried thinking of $\binom{n}{2}$ in terms of it's algebraic formula and as well as it's meaning "Number of ways to choose 2 things from n things" but I can't seem to correlate it anyhow with the tree.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  You just want a hint, rather than a full answer, right?

Comment: A hint as a starting point would be ideal, but then if I get stuck some help working towards the answer would be nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT

With $V$ the number of vertices, the $V \choose 2$ is of course the number of pairs of vertices in the tree. Now, think of possible pairings of vertices,  and how that relates to the path from each of those nodes to the root.

HINT 2

Use structural induction.

Comment: Ok, so I think I kind of see it now. Using pairs of nodes you could create a path from any node to the root using these pairs. ie. for a vertex v, you can pair it with it's parent to create one edge, then pair it with it's parent's parent which would represent another edge, and so on until you reach the root. This must mean there's at least as many pairs of nodes as there is edges from a node to the root! Does that make sense? Of course I could formalize it a bit more but i think I understand the gist.

Comment: @picklechips Actually, that doesn't work, since you may need the same 'segments' for multiple paths. You'll need a different strategy. Let me add another hint.